# NSSharingService Sharing Submenu

Tags: macos, cocoa, menu, menuitem, submenu

How do I add the Share submenu in a Mac app? An example is Safari > File > Share. I poked at the [Apple SharingServices sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SharingServices/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012313-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2), but it does not include a working menu item.

[image]

Right now I have a button that displays a picker of available sharing services when tapped:

```
NSMutableArray *shareItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[self.noteSynopsisView string]];
NSSharingServicePicker *sharingServicePicker = [[NSSharingServicePicker alloc] initWithItems:shareItems];
sharingServicePicker.delegate = self;
[sharingServicePicker showRelativeToRect:[self.shareButton bounds] ofView:self.shareButton preferredEdge:NSMaxYEdge];
```

I've also defined a Share submenu item under the File menu for my MainWindow.xib.

As I understand it, the NSSharingService list is being generated on the fly. So I can't really predefine the services to the menu item I have created in Interface Builder.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Look at NSSharingService's +sharingServicesForItems:. In a -validateMenuItem: method you could create a submenu using the -title and -image of the NSSharingServices it returns. Associate each service with each menu item, and point the action of each menu item at this:

```
- (IBAction)shareFromService:(id)sender {
  [[sender representedObject] performWithItems: arrayOfItemsToShare];
}
```

It's really quite simple. Apple did a good job on this one.

Comment: +1 A thanks from me as well! I was able to make this happen in the willOpen: delegate method of the NSMenu object.

Comment: Rather than validateMenuItem, it probably should be done in the menuNeedsUpdate: delegate.  Thanks for the direction.

Comment: I also note this does not include the "More" entry, not the Recent entries that the NSSharingServicePicker shows.

Answer (score 7):

I find the gist can help you easily create a submenu of proper services.
https://gist.github.com/eternalstorms/4132533

It's a NSSharingServicePicker category.

Answer (score 3):

Swift version:

```
extension NSSharingServicePicker {
    
    class func menu(forSharingItems items: [AnyHashable]) -> NSMenu? {
        
        let sharingServices = NSSharingService.sharingServices(forItems: items)
        
        if sharingServices.isEmpty {
            return nil
        }
        
        let menu = NSMenu()
        
        for service in sharingServices {
            
            let item = MenuItem(label: service.title, action: #selector(_openSharingService), target: self, userInfo: ["sharingItems": items])
            
            item.image = service.image
            item.representedObject = service
            item.target = self
            menu.addItem(item)
            
        }
        
        return menu
        
    }
    
    @objc class private func _openSharingService(sender: MenuItem) {
        
        guard let items = sender.userInfo["sharingItems"] as? [AnyHashable], let service = sender.representedObject as? NSSharingService else {
            return
        }
        
        service.perform(withItems: items)
        
    }
    
}

class MenuItem: NSMenuItem {
    
    var userInfo: [String : Any] = [:]
    
    init(label: String, action: Selector?, target: AnyObject?, userInfo: [String : Any]) {
        self.userInfo = userInfo
        super.init(title: label, action: action, keyEquivalent: "")
    }
    
    required init(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: decoder)
    }
    
}
```