# Disable "Share" submenu

Tags: macos, cocoa, menu, submenu

Cocoa automatically adds a Share submenu in the File menu of my app:

[image: Share menu]

**How can I disable this menu (or share commands globally) programmatically?** I need to disable it when the user hasn't yet purchased the app via IAP.

It doesn't seem I can use `validateUserInterfaceItem` as I did with other commands like `Save...`.

I understand via [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12378595/nssharingservice-sharing-submenu) that the menu uses `NSSharingService`. However it's not clear from that question how to disable the menu that is automatically added.

I could hard-code the index and disable the menu item, but that's rather icky. Also, because the app is localized, using the item's title would be gross as well.

Answer (score 4):

If you develop a document-based app, subclass NSDocumentController and override [`allowsAutomaticShareMenu`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsdocumentcontroller/2902308-allowsautomaticsharemenu) to return `false`.

```
class DocumentController: NSDocumentController {

    override var allowsAutomaticShareMenu: Bool {

        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! How do I get it to use my custom DocumentController?

Comment: Either programmatically invoke it in your NSApplicationDelegate's init() or put your DocumentController's instance in MainMenu.xib/Main.storyboard. See the very last part of https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocBasedAppProgrammingGuideForOSX/KeyObjects/KeyObjects.html.